# Exporting a .product for macosx results in a NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to build a product using Eclipse RCP for multiple systems (linux gtk/x86, macosx cocoa/x86_64, win32 win32/x86), but I keep on getting a NullPointerException when exporting specifically to macosx. I am running Linux, and the linux and win32 builds export fine, and without issues.

I am running Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) and have installed all the nescessary libraries for the project (it runs fine). As well, I am able to run it fine under OSX. I have also installed the nescessary delta to enable the multi-platform RCP export.

The following is the error log from the export. Note that the temp directory doesn't exist under .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/ after the export errors out.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.core 4 1 2011-05-05 11:32:59.049
!MESSAGE /home/meatcar/.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.macosx.cocoa.x86_64.xml:97: java.lang.NullPointerException
!STACK 0
/home/meatcar/.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.macosx.cocoa.x86_64.xml:97: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.tasks.BrandTask.execute(BrandTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor465.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:495)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.runScript(FeatureExportOperation.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.ProductExportOperation.run(ProductExportOperation.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BrandingIron.brandMac(BrandingIron.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BrandingIron.brand(BrandingIron.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.tasks.BrandTask.execute(BrandTask.java:46)
    ... 24 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BrandingIron.brandMac(BrandingIron.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BrandingIron.brand(BrandingIron.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.tasks.BrandTask.execute(BrandTask.java:46)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor465.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:495)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.runScript(FeatureExportOperation.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.ProductExportOperation.run(ProductExportOperation.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I killed a whole day on this, and got nowhere, and me excelent google skills haven't brought me back anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago and I think I solved it by removing the branding images ([Bug 292327](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=292327)). This bug was resolved a while ago (2009) but it might be a point to start from..

Comment: Sweet. You pointed me at the right path. Basically, we had application icons set up for windows, but not for linux or mac. Linux didn't mind so much, but clearly the mac export had an issue with the fact that windows had icons and mac didnt. I disabled all icons, and everything build without errors. :)